# ASP.NET 4.0 ListBox issue with HtmlEncoded ListItems

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a legacy ASP.NET 4.0 application we are updating for various security issues, we have a problem with listboxes and dropdownlists containing HtmlEncoded items. For ListItem text values containing apostrophes, the browser does not recognize the encoding in listboxes and dropdownlists, and thus fails decode the text back to an apostrophe when rendered.

For the requested example:

Consider Test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="TheListBox" ></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And its codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       TheListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("&#39;hello&#39;", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("hi")));
       TheListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("David's Test"), "hi"));

    }
}
```

The resultant page appears as follows:

[image: Test.aspx output]

In the SO question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931605/asp-net-4-0-dropdownlist-with-single-quotes-in-text/48870345#48870345), which is very similar, the OP selects an answer merely acknowledging that Microsoft documents the encoding of apostrophes as a change back when ASP.NET 4.0 was released. For us, however, that answer doesn't solve the *rendering* issue on the browser side, which we've seen in IE11 and FireFox. That is, we really have no problem with the encoding itself, but with the fact that the encoding isn't honored consistently.

The further problem for us is that some aspects of our application move the encoded data between listboxes for submission on postback, and the presence of the non-decoded apostrophe then causes the ASP.NET anti XSS checks to throw an exception on the request, thinking the value is malevolent, when it isn't. If the encoding is removed, the postback succeeds.

The site is already set to render controls with .Net 3.5 compatibility in web.config. We've tried removing this entirely, and then explicitly setting to 4.0 (presumably the default), neither of which makes any difference. I've considered rolling my own override of HtmlEncode to ignore strings containing apostrophes, but this seems draconian for the majority of instances where the browser renders encoded markup on non-listbox entities as expected, such as text boxes and labels.

Is there some other simple/obvious workaround or setting I've simply overlooked to overcome this problem? I've searched SO and other sites that indirectly discuss the apostrophe issue in general terms, but none seem to have a consistent solution specific to ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Although I realize this question hasn't received much response, I'm going to put some additional findings here that *almost* constitute an answer for the benefit of whomever else might be in the position of maintaining a legacy ASP.NET 4.0 site.

The real issue illustrated in the original post is that items in the ListBox are being *double-encoded.* This arises from the initial, explicit HtmlEncoding as illustrated in the source, *plus an additional HtmlEncode that is apparently being called at render time.*

The issue, we believe, is that **many**, but apparently not **all**, stock ASP.NET 4.x-series controls *automatically* call HtmlEncode when rendered.

We made this inference when noticing that the rendered content of a page with a simple ListBox control containing an item with an ampersand in it's text wrapped in an explicit HtmlEncode call was actually rendered with a hard '&', implying it had *already* been HtmlEncoded.

It appears that ASP **TextBox**, **DropDownList**, and **ListBox** controls *do* HtmlEncode their content at the time of rendering. The ASP **Label** control does *not*. The **GridView** control has an attribute that explicitly enables/disables HtmlEncoding. The Html equivalents of these controls, eg conventional HTML elements amended with the **runat="server"** attribute, are also HtmlEncoded at render-time.

The bottom line is that other than those listed above, any questions about whether a given control HtmlEncodes its vulnerable content can only be **absolutely** known by testing the control in question.

I will update this as I discover more info about determining which controls provide their own encoding.

**EDIT:**

Additional testing reveals both of the following controls are HtmlEncoded, both when value is explicitly set in markup or added/defined progrmmatically:

- HTML input type='hidden' tag when "runat='server'" is specified
- ASP:HiddenField control

I strongly suspect, but have not tested, any native HTML control with runat='server' would behave similarly.